# Get tablename from function

Tags: sql-server

I am creating tables. The tablenames are created dynamically.

Now the analysts say they need a field called 'dataset' that contains the name of the table.

Long story why they want it, apparently it is a deal killer if it's not in there.

So I was thinking of adding a computed column along the lines of

```
create table test
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    field1 nvarchar(256) null,
    dataset as table_name()   --<--  this is what I am looking for
)
```

I know of the functions `DB_USER()`, `@@SERVERNAME` and so on, is there something like that for the table? For example `CURRENT_TABLE()`?

Since I create the tables dynamically it is quite easy to add the column and fill it during creation but this question popped up and it keeps bugging me.

Comment: No, there isn't. And I can't imagine why they need to do so. You may use a computed column as: `DataSet AS 'Test'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not surprisingly, it seems there is no function that returns a table_name.
So I did what I normally do in such a case, create the tabel dynamically using sp_executesql and a string that I build, including c2 = @varTable_name.

```
declare @table_name as nvarchar(1000) = 'mytable'
declare @sql as nvarchar(1000) = 'create table ' + @table_name + '(
c1 INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
c2 AS ''' + @table_name +''');'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

I was just wondering if there was a function that I could use instead of the var @table_name

Comment: That will work, if your tables do not have special characters or spaces in them. If you are the person in control of naming them, that shouldn't be a problem. If you are not, you should look into using [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to create the table (in dynamic SQL, you should always use that in fact). I'll assume nobody is as silly to use single quotes in their table names ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In dynamic table creation, table name from one string. you can use same string to assign the table name to dataset value using default constraint.

```
create table test(
id int identity(1,1)
,field1  nvarchar(256) NULL
,dataset varchar(255) default  'test' 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function. There is a way to achieve your objective using a computed column though. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ttt(
    c1 INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    c2 AS 'ttt'
);
INSERT INTO ttt DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT*FROM ttt;
```

`c2` is a computed column that just returns a constant, that being the table name.